# Path based VirtualHosts with Passenger, Rack and Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, routes, rack

I'm trying to create a path-based versioning system for our API, something like:

```
GET api.ingeniapi.com/v1/items
```

vs

```
GET api.ingeniapi.com/v2/items/magic_new_thing
```

How do I setup Apache to route traffic from these **two paths** to **different rack applications**?

Right now I have something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName api.ingeniapi.com:443
  RackEnv production

  DocumentRoot /services/api_gateway/current/public

  <Directory /services/api_gateway/current/public >
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api.test.ingeniapi.com
  RackEnv production

  DocumentRoot /services/api_gateway/current/public

  <Directory /services/api_gateway/current/public >
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

As outlined here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri

You can set things up like this, using `PassengerBaseURI` and `Alias`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api.ingeniapi.com
  RackEnv production

  DocumentRoot /nowa_app/services/api_gateway/current/public
  <Directory /nowa_app/services/api_gateway/current/public >
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  # These have been added:
  Alias /v2 /nowa_app/services/api_gateway_v2/current/public
  <Location /v2>
      PassengerBaseURI /v2
      PassengerAppRoot /nowa_app/services/api_gateway_v2/current
  </Location>
  <Directory /nowa_app/services/api_gateway_v2/current/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```